# I am trying to write information from an excel spreadsheet to a Powerpoint using VBA macros

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am somewhat inexperienced in VBA, so my issues are probably pretty basic. I have a spreadsheet with a list of room numbers and I need them to be copied to a powerpoint presentation that will be running as a display.

My plan was to have a button on one slide that updates the presentation. So far, I have written code for that button that looks like this:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
Dim xldoc As Excel.Workbook
Dim Cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim shapeslide
Dim shapename
Dim shapetext

Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set xldoc = xlapp.ActiveWorkbook

Set rng = xldoc.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("a2:a" & Range("a" & xldoc.Sheets(Sheet1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
For Each Cell In rng

shapeslide = Sheet1.Range("a" & Cell.Row)
shapename = Sheet1.Range("b" & Cell.Row)
shapetext = Sheet1.Range("c" & Cell.Row)

ActivePresentation.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text = 
shapetext
Next Cell

ActivePresentation.Save
ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run

End Sub
```

But I am getting an error in the line `Set rng = xldoc.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("a2:a" & Range("a" & xldoc.Sheets(Sheet1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` which says "Subscript out of range."

For reference, here is the relevant excel document (this is a smaller and simpler version I was testing).

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      Index          |     Shape Name   |      Value          |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          1          |     Subtitle 2   |      Room 133       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          2          |   Placeholder 2  |      Room 140       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          3          |   Placeholder 2  |      Room 220       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          4          |   Placeholder 2  |      Room 300       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

I know this is just going to be a simple bug, I know what the "subscript out of range" message means, but I cannot figure out what is causing it.

Comment: The fix from Tim Williams worked, my second Range method needed to be called with `xldoc.Sheets(Sheet1)` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
Set rng = xldoc.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("a2:a" & _
      Range("a" & xldoc.Sheets(Sheet1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

should maybe be:

```
With xldoc.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = .Range("a2:a" & .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
```

Assuming the tab name of the sheet is "Sheet1".

EDIT: rest of code

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
    Dim xldoc As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim shapeslide
    Dim shapename
    Dim shapetext
    Dim sht As Excel.WorkSheet

    'see if Excel is open
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error Goto 0

    If xlapp Is Nothing then
        Msgbox "Excel is not open!"
        Exit sub
    End If

    Set xldoc = xlapp.ActiveWorkbook
    Set sht = xldoc.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set rng = sht.Range("a2:a" & sht.Range("a" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each Cell In rng.Cells

        shapeslide = sht.Range("a" & Cell.Row)
        shapename = sht.Range("b" & Cell.Row)
        shapetext = sht.Range("c" & Cell.Row)
        ActivePresentation.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes( _
                shapename).TextEffect.Text = shapetext
    Next Cell

    ActivePresentation.Save
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem. Unfortunately, I now have an error on this line: `Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")` with the message "Activex component can't create object." I'm sorry to just be throwing bugs at you, but this is the part of VBA I am least comfortable with, and if you have any idea what I did wrong I would appreciate it.

Comment: See my update above - you will see errors if Excel is not already open.